# Expressions are not allowed at the top level

Tags: swift

I am a beginning Swift programmer.

The following code seems to compile fine in Xcode 7.0 Playground (no visible errors):

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

//#!/usr/bin/env xcrun swift

import WebKit

let application = NSApplication.sharedApplication()
application.setActivationPolicy(NSApplicationActivationPolicy.Regular)
let window = NSWindow()
window.setContentSize(NSSize(width:800, height:600))
window.styleMask = NSTitledWindowMask | NSClosableWindowMask | NSMiniaturizableWindowMask
window.center()
window.title = "Minimal Swift WebKit Browser"
window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(window)

class WindowDelegate: NSObject, NSWindowDelegate {

    func windowWillClose(notification: NSNotification) {
        NSApplication.sharedApplication().terminate(0)
    }
}
let windowDelegate = WindowDelegate()
window.delegate = windowDelegate

class ApplicationDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    var _window: NSWindow

    init(window: NSWindow) {
        self._window = window
    }

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(notification: NSNotification) {
        let webView = WebView(frame: self._window.contentView!.frame)
        self._window.contentView!.addSubview(webView)
        webView.mainFrame.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://www.apple.com")!))
    }
}
```

When pasting that exact same code into the "AppDelegate.swift" file of a new Cocoa application for OSX, I get 7 errors, all exactly the same: "Expressions are not allowed at the top level".

Through searching I've deduced that the Playground allows things that normal projects do not and the errors are occurring because the expressions are "outside of a class or instance method".

However I'm not sure how the program could be modified in order to build correctly.

Comment: Move your variable declarations into a method of an object. How about the init of your ApplicaitonDelegate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, normal projects do not allow code at the top level, because there is no obvious time for it to run. You need to decide when your activation policy and window/delegate code should run (that is, move that code inside of a method). I suggest `applicationDidFinishLaunching(_:)`, as it is called when your app is finished launching and is a common place to do this kind of setup. The finished code would read:

```
import WebKit

class WindowDelegate: NSObject, NSWindowDelegate {
    func windowWillClose(notification: NSNotification) {
        NSApplication.sharedApplication().terminate(0)
    }
}

class ApplicationDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    var _window: NSWindow

    init(window: NSWindow) {
        self._window = window
    }

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(notification: NSNotification) {
        let webView = WebView(frame: self._window.contentView!.frame)
        self._window.contentView!.addSubview(webView)
        webView.mainFrame.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://www.apple.com")!))

        let application = NSApplication.sharedApplication()
        application.setActivationPolicy(NSApplicationActivationPolicy.Regular)
        let window = NSWindow()
        window.setContentSize(NSSize(width:800, height:600))
        window.styleMask = NSTitledWindowMask | NSClosableWindowMask | NSMiniaturizableWindowMask
        window.center()
        window.title = "Minimal Swift WebKit Browser"
        window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(window)

        let windowDelegate = WindowDelegate()
        window.delegate = windowDelegate
    }
}
```

Comment: This is great. It compiled and ran correctly but it just shows up as blank grey window with no webpage loaded (it should load Apple homepage). Would you be able to tell me why or should I open another question? Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: My best guess from the code you've presented here is that you have two different `window`s. If you intend for your `webView` to be added to the window titled "Minimal Swift WebKit Browser", then the existence and usage of the `_window` property is misguided. You would of course want to work with the `window` local variable that you initialize and set properties of in `applicationDidFinishLaunching()`. That's the window that needs to have a subview added.

Comment: OK, thanks. I'll probably have to open another question since I just noticed there are messages in the target ouput window such as: "Failed to connect (window) outlet from (NSObject) to (NSWindow): missing setter or instance variable"
But thanks for all your help with this question! You definitely resolved what I initially came in for.